# How to initialise positions on a nxn dimension with ASCII? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, ascii

I am trying to assign letters and numbers to an array with any given nxn dimension. For example a 4x4 array would be
`p[0][0] p[0][1] p[0][2] p[0][3]`

`p[1][0] p[1][1] p[1][2] p[1][3]`

`p[2][0] p[2][1] p[2][2] p[2][3]`

`p[3][0] p[3][1] p[3][2] p[3][3]`

I want to assign each row a letter of the alphabet and each column a number so that p[0][0] = A1, p[0][1] = B1. Just like this:

`A1 B1 C1 D1 ...` until the nth number of the alphabet (n1)

`A2 B2 ...`

`...` and until the nth number (An)

So far I can only create an array of given dimensions and assign one by one some specific letters and values:

```
public static String[] intPos(int dimension) {
      String [] [] p = new String [dimension] [dimension];
      for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i ++) {
        for (int j =0; j < dimension; j ++) {
          p [i] [j] = 0;
        }
      }
      String p [0][1] = "B1";
      String p [0][3] = "D1";
      String p [2][1] = "B3";
      System.out.println("[" + p [0][1] + "," + p[0][3] + "," + p[2][1] + "]");

}
```

However I do not know how to move forward from here. The rows are the numbers and the columns are letters. For example every p[any number][3] starts with D.I couldn't
write this relation. 
Thanks for helping!

So far this is the last state that I have reached:

```
public static String[] initialisePositions(int dimension) {
      char [] alphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};       
      int [] nums = new int [dimension];
      for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i ++) {
        nums [i] = i + 1;
      }
      int [] [] p = new int [dimension] [dimension];
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i ++){
          for (int j = 0; j <dimension; j ++){
            p [i][j] = ?
          }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But need help on how to concat list of letters on the column and numbers on the rows for p[i][j].

Comment: Hint: chars can be treated as integer types: `char letter = 'A'; letter += 1; // letter is now 'B'`.

Comment: How am I going to implement that in my code though?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very straight forward way to do it. It will do 'A-Za-z'. You have to modify to handle more cases than that.

```
public static String[][] intPos(int dimension) {
    if (dimension <= 0) return null;
    String [][] data = new String[dimension][dimension];
    for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
        char letter = 'A';
        for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
            data[row][col] = String.format("%c%d", letter, row+1);
            letter += 1;
            if (letter == 'Z') letter = 'a';
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do it differently, I edited the question, from there how can I proceed? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KaleJoe See [`String.Format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). Example `p [i][j] = String.format("%c%d", alphabet[j], nums[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Run the for Loop and concatenate string array which stores {A,B,C,D..} with the Row index {1,2,3..} and asssign it to the array values

Comment: an example or code samle could have been great.. We dont want people to visualize the solution you talk about, but we want to understand and learn it!